# How to run Django with Uvicorn webserver?

Tags: python, django, uvicorn

I have a Django project running on my local machine with dev server `manage.py runserver` and I'm trying to run it with Uvicorn before I deploy it in a virtual machine. So in my virtual environment I installed `uvicorn` and started the server, but as you can see below it fails to find Django static css files.

```
(envdev) user@lenovo:~/python/myproject$ uvicorn myproject.asgi:application --port 8001
Started server process [17426]

Waiting for application startup.
ASGI 'lifespan' protocol appears unsupported.
Application startup complete.
Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

INFO:     127.0.0.1:45720 - "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/base.css
INFO:     127.0.0.1:45720 - "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
Not Found: /static/admin/css/dashboard.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/dashboard.css
INFO:     127.0.0.1:45724 - "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css
Not Found: /static/admin/css/responsive.css
INFO:     127.0.0.1:45726 - "GET /static/admin/css/responsive.css HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

Uvicorn has an option `--root-path` so I tried to specify the directory where these files are located but there is still the same error (path is correct). How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When not running with the built-in development server, you'll need to either

- use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) which does this as a Django/WSGI middleware (my recommendation)
- use [the classic staticfile deployment procedure which collects all static files into some root](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#deployment) and a static file server is expected to serve them. Uvicorn doesn't seem to support static file serving, so you might need something else too (see e.g. https://www.uvicorn.org/deployment/#running-behind-nginx).
- (very, very unpreferably!) [have Django serve static files like it does in dev](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

Comment: Thanks for your recommandation! learning new things everyday )

Comment: Annoyingly, whitenoise doesn't appear to suggest that it can be used with asgi (in several places it mentions it "works with wsgi"), which meant it took me ages to realise it would just work with Django running asgi

Answer (score 8):

Add below code your settings.py file

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', )
```

Add below code in your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [.
.....] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Then run below command but static directory must exist

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

start server

```
uvicorn main.asgi:application --host 0.0.0.0
```